# Refactoring manual join loops

Tags: python, join

I have some code that joins between multiple lists in memory based on a common dictionary field and a condition. I figure there's a more efficient way of writing this code but I'm not sure what it looks like right now. The data's order is not enforced and can appear in any order.

```
# update component set component.build_status = latest.build_status INNER JOIN latest on component.name= latest.component where component.environment = latest.environment AND latest.build_status = 'failure'

  for component in state["components"]:
      for component_data in state["latest"]:
          if component_data["environment"] == component["environment"] and \
             component_data["name"] == component["name"] and \
             component_data["build_success"] == "failure":
              component["build_success"] = "failure"
```

**How do I refactor this join?**

I figure I could do some thing with classes and lookups rather than loops. But I'm not seeing it as the code might be simple enough. What do you think?

---

**The context**: I'm writing a build server. I have a model that consists of environment, component, latest, command, running.
The problem is I have nested loops searching for matching items between the individual collections and copying status flags between them. I have to join before I copy the status flag.

What the SQL would approximately be is above the code.

Here's a cut down view of the model. I've deleted a lot of data from it.

State in the code example corresponds to "app" below:

```
{
    "app": {
        "latest": [
            {
                "name": "ansible-inventory/tools",
                "environment": "production",
                "commands": [
                    {
                        "name": "run",
                        "environment": "production",
                        "progress": 100,
                        "buildIdentifier": "0",
                        "build_number": 4,
                        "build_success": "success"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "test",
                        "environment": "production",
                        "progress": 100,
                        "buildIdentifier": "0",
                        "build_number": 2,
                        "build_success": "success"
                    }
                ],
                "build_success": "success"

        ],
        "components": [

            {
                "name": "ansible-inventory/tools",
                "status": "ready",
                "command": "validate",
                "environment": "production",
                "progress": 100,
                "build_success": "success"
            },
            {
                "name": "ansible-local/dev",
                "status": "ready",
                "command": "validate",
                "environment": "production",
                "progress": 100,
                "build_success": "success"
            }
        ],
        "running": [],
        "environments": [
            {
                "name": "home",
                "progress": 100,
                "status": "ready",
                "facts": "12 tasks, 2 components",
                "build_success": "success"
            },
            {
                "name": "production",
                "progress": 100,
                "status": "ready",
                "facts": "12 tasks, 2 components",
                "build_success": "success"
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: This is a very long question. You should create a [mcve], with focus on "minimal".

Comment: I've removed most of everything, hopefully it's minimal enough now.

Comment: you should definitely use pandas here.. Easy to manipulate dataframes.

Comment: @SamuelSquire can you post a example of your model

Comment: I've added a cut down view of my model.

Comment: are the names unique? and in the same corresponding place in the list ?

Comment: A component name can appear in different environments, so there could be many component and latest items with the same name.

Comment: @SamuelSquire are they in the same corresponding places ? or it can appear in any position on the list?

Comment: They can appear anywhere in the list the order isn't enforced.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. For code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [help]